# Trouble installing acorn-dynamic-import node module to Ionic Android project

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

Anyone have a resolution for this issue. After install the acorn and acorn dynamic import I'm facing this error. This is related to the Android build using the ionic and cordova.

```
ionic cordova build android
TypeError: Cannot set property 'dynamicImport' of undefined
    at injectDynamicImport (C:\git\<PROJECT_NAME>\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn-dynamic-import\lib\inject.js:27:31)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\git\<PROJECT_NAME>\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn-dynamic-import\lib\index.js:17:46)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\git\<PROJECT_NAME>\node_modules\webpack\lib\Parser.js:9:15)
```

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered a similar problem.
I use Arch Linux and for the situation where you can exclude some unnecessary dependencies the Solution can be found here:

https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/60826

It appears as if thee are some dependencies (probably deprecated) causing the issue.

At best take a look at the suggested patch.

I've successfully applied the patch.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with related to the "dist" directory was missing. Sometimes when developer upload source code, they forget to upload the dist directory. It's also a size factor, being the dist directories are large. If you dont have the original dist folder, you will need to re install  --save to your node_module directory.